# WordPress, modular content, and syndication

Tags: plugins, api

I am trying to sketch out a possible Wordpress based solution by which content is authored in a modular way, with an arbitrary number of different modular blocks of content, (similar to Sir Trevor https://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/) that would also allow full content to be pushed (or pulled) to other separate WordPress installs. (The essential idea being that a set of editors have access to a set of simple modular blocks to build content which is likely to be duplicated across different separate sites and another set of editors have access to a more complicated set of blocks to build content that is not necessarily meant to be duplicated.)

It seems likely I could architect something with ACF, but I'm not sure that I could reliably duplicate that custom field based content between WordPress installs. Is there an obvious solution I'm overlooking or just ignorant of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there seems to be no option for building a WordPress-based system in this way, short of building something yourself.